# this is the index.htm doc which is supposed to run a .swf file, the page just loads and nothing happens, the flash doesnt play, any help?

Tags: html, xml, flash

```
<html>  
    <head>    
        <title>My Website </title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var flashvars = {};
        var params = {allowFullScreen:true};
        var attributes = {};
        swfobject.embedSWF("preview.swf", "nav", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf",flashvars,params,attributes);
        </script>
        <style>
        body{
            margin-left:0px;
            margin-top:0px;
            margin-right:0px;
            margin-bottom:0px;
        }   
        </style>
    </head>  
    <body>

        <div id="content" align="center">
                    <div id="nav">
                            <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
                    </div>



    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post your css for div#nav?  Without a minimum height it might not display any content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the link to the SwfObject JS file

Have you also uploaded the swfobject.js file to the server?

Comment: yep i have added the file and uploaded it to the server but still nothing when i run the site.

Comment: whats the server address?  I can have a look?

Comment: you mean the actual link to my site?, am new to using this site so am not sure how safe it is to post that?

Comment: YES. what is the url (I dont want your street address).

Comment: I get unhandled load errors with this url, is this loader being supplied some bad file names or paths?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
audioBack.jpgFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
audioBack.jpgFailed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server.
close.jpgFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
close.jpgFailed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server.
bg1.jpgFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
bg1.jpgFailed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: I have started to re-upload the .jpg files individually , i noticed there were some mising! this might just be the problem, may take about 10 mins to do, will let you know what happens

Comment: Problem solved! thank you for your help, i didnt upload the images properly and thats were the problem was. Many thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a min-height on your nav div:

```
div#nav { min-height:100px; }
```

Comment: i couldn't find the div nav on my .css docs, will look again and try as suggested.

Comment: There is no rule for it in the code you provided above, you should add it after the body rules.

Comment: ive added this and uploaded the site again, still nothing. The page just loads but nothing happens. The music plays in the background but thats all.

Comment: If the music is coming from your nav but you can't see it then the problem lies somewhere in your html/css.  Can you put up a link to a working example?

Comment: that the link to the site but after it loads, nothing comes. Its a template am playing around with, i have looked in the .css file but there isnt anything relating to div nav. I added it to the index page and uploaded but nothing happened again.